# Reference for algebro-geometric definition of the $\cup$-product in (sheaf) cohomology.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Can anyone give me a reference on how the $\cup$-product of sheaf cohomology is defined? I read somewhere that it has to do with the Yoneda pairing of Ext, but my naive approach did not work, because $H^i(X,\mathcal{F}) \cong \text{Ext}^i(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})$ and $H^j(X,\mathcal{G}) \cong \text{Ext}^j(\mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{G})$ do not pair up.

Comment: First, the cup product is from $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\otimes H^j(X,\mathcal{G}) \to H^{i+j}(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})$. Second, did you check google/wikipedia/nlab? If so, where were the parts of their explanation where you were stuck?

Comment: This makes a bit more sense, so if $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{G} = \mathcal{O}_X$ I can compose with multiplication to end in $\mathcal{O}$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product) only covers singular homology, the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cup+product#in_abelian_sheaf_cohomology) just mentions tensor products of sheaves, and so called ["abelian sheaf cohomology"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/abelian+sheaf+cohomology) which is an article full of words I don't know and seems to be about generalisations or more general contexts in which sheaf cohomology can be considered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a really concrete definition without Yoneda product, so I write it just in case.

Pick an affine cover $\mathfrak U$ of $X$. An  element of $H^i(X,F)$ can be though as a cocycle $(f_{I})$ where $f_I \in \Gamma(F, U_I)$ (I hope the abuse of notation is clear), and similarly for an element of $H^j(X,G)$. You can now simply define the product as $(f_I) \cup (g_J) = (f_I \otimes g_J)$ when you only consider the disjoint pairs of index $I,J$. This is by definition in $H^{i+j}(X, F \otimes G)$.

If you want to use the Yoneda product, there is a natural map $$ H^i(X,F) \otimes H^j(X,G) = Ext^i(\mathcal O_X,F) \otimes Ext^j(\mathcal O_X, G) \to Ext^i(\mathcal O_X, F) \otimes Ext^j(F, G \otimes F)$$ and you can apply the Yoneda product to the last term.

Remark : I think the two definitions coincide but I never see where it was written down formally.

Comment: I believe the proof of cup product = Yoneda product is rather formal once you have proven that the cup product is a monoidal structure in $D(X)$. However, I am always unsure whether a sign shows up because of the anticommutativity of $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}A[1]\otimes B[1]@>>>(A[1]\otimes B)[1]\\@VVV@VVV\\(A\otimes B[1])[1]@>>>(A\otimes B)[2]\end{CD}$$You can also look at the "other Yoneda pairing" $$Ext^i(O_X,F)\otimes Ext^j(O_X,G)\to Ext^i(G,F\otimes G)\otimes Ext^j(O_X,G)\to Ext^{i+j}(O_X,F\otimes G)$$ So yes, a source which makes the connections with the 3 of them would be welcomed.

Comment: @Roland : Dear Roland, thanks a lot for your comment, this is really appreciated ! I totally agree that would be great if we could see if the two Yoneda products coincide, and if we need to add a sign or not. In fact I needed this myself and didn't find anything a few month ago, but I hope it's written down somewhere ...

Comment: Thank you, I have two further questions: For the first definition we need that sheaf cohomology (i.e. derived functors of $\Gamma$) and Čhech cohomolgy are the same, right? This is for example satisfied if $X$ is a noetherian separated scheme, and $F, G$ are quasi-coherent. For the second one is the map $\text{Ext}(\mathcal{O},G) \rightarrow \text{Ext}(F,  F \otimes G)$ obtained by tensorising with $F$?

Comment: @Roland Is $D(X)$ the derived category of the category of sheaves on $X$?

Comment: @red_trumpet : 1) exactly. 2) The map I wrote is indeed obtained by tensoring if you're thinking of $Ext^i$ as an equivalence classes of exact sequences. Alternatively by abstract nonsense since $Ext^i$ are the derived functors of Hom it's actually enough to construct this map for Hom, where it's again given by tensoring with F.

Comment: @red_trumpet Rather in this context, the derived category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, but it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Trying to work this out I had the following problem: $F \otimes -$ need not be exact, right? So when I have an extension $[0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \dotsb \rightarrow G \rightarrow 0]$, and take the tensor product with $F$, it need not be an extension afterwards. Somewhat analogously I was not able to prove that $G \mapsto Ext^i(F, F \otimes G)$ is a $\delta$-functor, because tensorising with $F$ need not be exact. So I don't understand how those maps are defined.

Comment: @red_trumpet : You are right, the map does not seem to be defined in general or you need to assume that $F$ or $G$ is flat. The "concrete definition" still works of course.